# How to check ValidPage in CodedUI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am using Code first method instead of record method. I have login page from which i am moving to next page that is home page.

```
 public HomePage SubmitClick(string userName, string Password)
        {
                HtmlEdit txtUsername = new HtmlEdit(_browserWindow);
                txtUsername.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, "txt_empid");
                txtUsername.Text = userName;


                HtmlEdit txtPassword = new HtmlEdit(_browserWindow);
                txtPassword.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, "txt_password");
                txtPassword.Text = Password;


            HtmlInputButton btnSubmit = new HtmlInputButton(_browserWindow);
            btnSubmit.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlInputButton.PropertyNames.Id, "btn_submit");
            Mouse.Click(btnSubmit);
            return new HomePage(_browserWindow);
        }
```

Redirecting is working fine. My question is how to identify if the open page is valid or not.
What i am planning is to check for some controls like `button` and `hyperlinks` if they exist then page is valid. Is it a good method.

Comment: try checking the url is as expected

Comment: @barakcaf with that i will not be sure if all the controls of the page are proper

Comment: the only way i know  to validate all the controls are proper is to search for them individually, or take a snapshot of the page and compare it to a master. but, you should wait for the page to finish loading using the WaitForControlReady() on a key control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give `_browserwindow.WaitForControlReady()` it will wait till the `browserwindow`  completely loads the page.
Once the page is loaded use `Assert` to check for the title of the page whether it is the same  as expected.

```
_browserwindow.WaitForControlReady();
WinTabPage nextPage = new WinTabPage(_browserwindow);
Assert.AreEqual("Home Page", nextPage.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare the URL of the next Page.If its the URL thats required then the test case passes.

`Uri url = BrowserwindowObj.Uri;`

This gives the URL of the current browser Page.

Comment: question remains the same. What if it goes to the next page and none of the/some of the controls are loaded ?